# Hive's unix_timestamp and from_unixtime functions

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am under the impression that ***unix_timestamp*** and ***from_unixtime*** Hive functions are 'reverse' of each other.

When I try to convert timestamp string to seconds in Hive:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp('10-Jun-15 10.00.00.000000 AM', 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.MS a');
```

I get 1418176800.

When I try to convert 1418176800 to timestamp string:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(1418176800, 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.MS a');
```

I get 10-Dec-14 10.00.00.120 AM, which is obviously not equal to the original.

Can someone explain what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the language manual:

> Convert time string with given pattern to Unix time stamp (in seconds)
>   The result of this function is in seconds.

Your result changes with the milliseconds portion of the date, but the unix functions only support seconds. For example:

`SELECT unix_timestamp('10-Jun-15  10.00.00 AM', 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a');`

1433930400

`SELECT from_unixtime(1433930400, 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a');`

10-Jun-15 10.00.00 AM

Comment: Thanks. I got it wrong on the sub-second part. `ss` instead of `MS`. It's all working now.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use from unix_timestamp as you have in your second query. Additionally your statement has a formatting in it that gives the result where DEC is used in steads of 12.  See `dd-MM-yy`. Don't specify a format and it should work. See the examples below.

You are however correct that `from_unixtime()` and `unix_timestamp()` are used to convert back and forth from time string.

```
select unix_timestamp('2015-04-09 03:04:26') from dual;
```

results in "1428566666"

```
select from_unixtime(1428566666) from dual;
```

results in "2015-04-09 03:04:26"