# conversion from string to timestamp is not working

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, unix-timestamp

The data in the table as below.
The column jobdate data type is string.

jobdate
1536945012211.kc
1536945014231.kc
1536945312809.kc

I want to convert it to time stamp as the format `2018-12-205 06:15:10.505`

I have tried the following queries but returning NULL.

```
select jobdate,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr(jobdate,1,14),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS')) from job_log;
select jobdate,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(jobdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS')) from job_log;
select jobdate,cast(date_format(jobdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS') as timestamp) from job_log;
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related, maybe duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701847/hives-unix-timestamp-and-from-unixtime-functions

Answer (score 1):

Original timestamps are too long, use 10 digits:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(cast(substr('1536945012211.kc',1,10) as int),'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
OK
2018-09-257 10:10:12.000
Time taken: 0.832 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select from_unixtime(cast(substr('1536945012211.kc',1,10) as int),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS');
OK
2018-09-14 10:10:12.000
Time taken: 0.061 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your response