# How can i add days to a Hive timestamp without loosing hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I am using Hive 2.6.5 and when i want to add days to my timestamp, it doesn't keep the hours, minutes and seconds.

Exemple

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_add("2021-01-15 09:34:21",2),'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

in addition to that it returns a wrong result as :

```
2020-12-01 **00:00:00**
```

I would like it to return the value
`2021-01-17 09:34:21`

Thank you

Comment: wouldn't that be because your use of unix_timestamp doesn't include the time component so it's truncating the time when it's being cast?  or consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701847/hives-unix-timestamp-and-from-unixtime-functions or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399544/add-minutes-to-datetime-in-hive

Comment: It seems like the function `add_date` truncates the hours,minutes and seconds. However I don't know how to add days to a date with the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` without losing the `HH:m:ss` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. date_add truncates
2. Unnecessary unix_timestamp+from_unixtime conversion

Convert to timestamp, add interval:

```
SELECT timestamp("2021-01-15 09:34:21") + interval '2' day;
```

Result:

```
2021-01-17 09:34:21.0
```

Timestamp is displayed with zero millisecond part, it is default timestamp representation.
If you want it as string without milliseconds, format using date_format or simply take substr()

```
SELECT date_format(timestamp("2021-01-15 09:34:21") + interval '2' day,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Result:

```
2021-01-17 09:34:21
```

And the same using substr:

```
SELECT substr(timestamp("2021-01-15 09:34:21") + interval '2' day,1,19)
```

If you need to calculate interval dynamically and your Hive version does not support it, see this example:

```
with mytable as (
select timestamp("2021-01-15 09:34:21") ts, 2 d
)
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(ts) + (d*24*60*60))
from mytable
```

Result:

```
2021-01-17 09:34:21
```

Comment: It works great. I just added simple quote to the day's number : 
`SELECT date_format(timestamp("2021-01-15 09:34:21") + INTERVAL '2' DAY,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');`

Comment: @Azo Hmm... It worked without quotes on demo.gethue.com. Added quotes.

Comment: Can the value of Interval be a value of a column ? for exemple :
SELECT myTable.col1, date_format(timestamp("2021-01-15 09:34:21") + INTERVAL myTable.col1 DAY,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') FROM myTable ;

Comment: @Azo Docs says it is possible since Hive 2.2.0 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+types

Comment: @Azo If it does not work in your Hive then convert to unix_timestamp (returns seconds), add interval in seconds (days* 24*60*60), convert result to timestamp (from_unixtime)

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in the description, I work with Hive 1.2. So the second method with adding the interval as seconds works fine. Thanks!